# Where does Dumprep.exe save dump files

Tags: windows-xp, dump

OS: Windows XP

I just disabled windows built-in dumprep.exe in system error reporting and also want to delete all dump files. I've tried to use ccleaner to scan windows > memory dumps but found nothing. It seems not related. Where does Dumprep.exe save dump files?

Comment: Normally C:\Windows\Minidump, or search the drive for ".dmp"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your `My Computer` icon and choose `Properties`.  Select the `Advanced` tab and then click the `Settings...` button in the `Startup and Recovery` area.  This will show you a window with a textbox near the bottom that gives the location of the dump files.  It most likely uses an environment variable (`%SystemRoot%` on my machine, which corresponds to my `C:\Windows\System` folder).